# Prevent open in new tab/window

Tags: html, css, iframe, tabs, hyperlink

I have a website that has a music player in one of the corners. Because I didn't want the music to stop everytime the user changes part of the website, I used an iFrame for the content. So when someone clicks the menu buttons, all that changes is the source of the iFrame.

Now the only problem is if someone tries to open one of the sub-pages in a new tab/window. All they get is black text on a white background, with the content that was supposed to be in the iFrame.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Oh, and the page this is about is [www.sinjabe.com](http://www.sinjabe.com)  if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most logical solution (to me...) would be to detach the music player from the page; have the music player open in a different window / tab. You can have the music player in a pop-up window when the visitor of your site requests it / clicks on it.

Other solutions like detecting if the content has a parent frame, will lead to multiple music players if someone opens a page in a new tab / window.

Comment: Opening a media player in another window will be highly annoying. Any band website has this, so there must be a solution.

Comment: @Rickard: Don't they tend to be made entirely in Flash? Can you give an example of a website with the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your sub-pages to detect if they are loaded in an iframe like this:

```
(window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;
```

and then load or redirect to the full template as needed.

Comment: How/where would I write this? I'm not that good with javascript or anything like that. I'd like to be, but I'm not :)

Comment: This should be placed in the content that should be loaded in an iframe. The code will detect whether it was indeed loaded in an iframe. If it returns false, you should take action as needed to load the full template.

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your sub pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location == window.parent.location)
    this.window.location = 'main_site.html';
</script>
```

-- Give credit for this one @George Cummins for writting such a short conditional statment :)

This will redirect any direct incomming trafic on your subpages to your main page. I must warn you though, that iframes for displaying such content are highly SEO unefficient, and URL useless in terms of history mapping (back button will not work) and link sharing, because the main URL doesn't change while you click on menu buttons.

Comment: Do you have a better solution than iFrames for having a media player that doesn't stop playing when I change subpages? If you do that would be great! :)

Comment: Well, there is a way, but is quite complex. You can make for example div content placeholders, and fill it with data by ajax. If you want that to be SEO friendly, you should also change the URL depending on what you are loading. You can check how Google supports ajax content loading here: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html That way the browser will not reload to reset the player, the URL will change so it can be coppied and Google will realize the site structure.

Comment: The other solution is that the website is made entirely in Adobe Flash. Flash sites don't need reloading to change the content as they can load the whole site from one file or dynamically load assets need for display.